# How to use onclick with name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, html-lists

I have a multiple ul's (HTML lists) in my website and the structure of that ul's are as following:

```
<ul id="today_match_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" name= "today_group_'+counter+'" class="contests"><li id="'+page_url+'" class="fixture"><table class="fixture_table" border="1"><tr><td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="today_checkbox_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="checkbox"></td><td id="today_status_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="status" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ status1 +'</td><td id="today_localteam_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="winner_localteam" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ localteam +'</td><td id="today_goalsLocalteam_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="goals_localteam" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ goals_localteam +'</td><td class="space" id = "'+static_id+'_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter+'" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">-</td><td id="today_goalsVisitorteam_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="goals_visitorteam" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ goals_visitorteam +'</td><td id="today_visitorteam_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="visitorteam" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ visitorteam +'</td><td id="today_htScore_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="ht_score" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'">'+ ht_score +'</td><td id="today_startTime_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="start_time" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'"></td><td id="today_iddaaCode_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'" class="iddaa_code" name="today_link_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'"></td></tr></table></li></ul>
```

all the values inside the td's are from an xml file and each ul have an id,class and name.
If you notice I have a table inside the li of each ul and the first td of that table is  a checkbox .
Now, the problem is that each ul is a fixture in my live score website and when I click on that ul I should get a page of results, But when I link the Id of the table to onclick handler it interferences with the click of checkbox (I mean when i click on the checkbox the link is clicked and when I click on the link the checkbox is selected) I can not make inner table for all the td's excluding the checkbox (because of CSS reasons) So I tried to give the same name attribute for all the td's of the tables excluding the td of the checkbox and link them with onclick but it did not work.
I want to know if there is any way that could be useful to used here?
The onclick handler:

```
$("name[today_link_"+ counter +'_'+ today_counter+"]").click(function() {
                    testwindow = window.open(page_url, "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height="+screen.height+",resizable=1");
                    testwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
                });
```

Comment: `today_match_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +` <- FAIL

Comment: `<ul id="today_match_'+ counter +'_'+ today_counter +'"` what (server side) template engine are you using to compiling `counter` and `today_counter`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name = today_link_"+ counter +"_"+ today_counter+"]).
```

Comment: it did not work i added also +"]" at the end of it and it did not work

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake.try it now

Comment: You should probably still nest quotes for the name literal.

Comment: I tried each possible way of quotes but it is not responding at all

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name ="today_link_" + counter + "_" + today_counter ]').on('click', function() {
   dostuffhereboundonclick();
});
```

Make sure name is cross quoted properly (nested quotes).